# post_type how to get 1 title

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have done some research on this and couldnt find anything about it.

I got 4 different post.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'post',
  'order'    => 'ASC' );              
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
the_title();            
endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

this code shows all the titels, the output is like this :

```
 1post2post3post4post
 1post2post3post4post
 1post2post3post4post
 1post2post3post4post
```

but what i want is this:

```
 1post
 2post
 3post
 4post
```

How do i get this?

EDIT: Made some changes with the help of @Vincent. How do i get this 2 parts of code to work with each other?

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'cubeportfolio',
'order'    => 'ASC'
);              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
<?php    
the_permalink(); 
endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();                            
?>  

<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'order'    => 'ASC'
);              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
<?php    
echo get_the_title()."<br/>";   
endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();                            
?>
```

Comment: `the_title() . '<br>';` is oneof many ways

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, yes i did that, but like i said still have 4 posts i just want 1. i added my hole code maybe you understand now wat i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** What to you get with this part only ?

```
           <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'=> 'post',
                     'order'    => 'ASC'
                     );              

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if($the_query->have_posts() ) : 
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    
                       echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" >'.get_the_title().'</a>'.'<br/>';   
                    endwhile; 
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();                            
            ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but, the output is now like:
 1post
 2post
 3post
 4post
 1post
 2post
 3post
 4post
 1post
 2post
 3post
 4post
 1post
 2post
 3post
 4post
still getting four rows of the one row i want

Comment: Try commenting the foreach part :    `<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ) ?>` I think you get this result because you iterate with the while loop in addition to the foreach one.

Comment: I did out comment the foreach part, but weirdly enough there was no change in the output. even no error

Comment: Hi vincent van you still help me?

Comment: what if you remove the while part instead ?

Comment: then i will get the titel of cubeportofolio, but i want the titel of post

Comment: i've edited my answer, try the code above, it's pretty hard to debug with suppositions ^^

Comment: i am getting the right titels, i dont have any urls.

Comment: i realy appreciate that you are helping me @vincent.
The thing now is am getting both, buth the link is not good. I need the link of permalink. and thats what i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

After Edits - try this code

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks abdo i had this already, but i want the permalink of 'post_type'            => 'cubeportfolio' and the title of  'post_type' => 'post'
thats why its so difficult for me

Comment: I think this query not work true , i will try search again

Comment: Hi abdo, i wanted to know if you did find something